# How to Use Kaleo Workflow to Edit and Delete Record in Liferay

Tags: liferay, workflow

I am using Liferay 6.2 Enterprise Edition.

I have implemented Kaleo workflow when adding new record to an entity, I have no issue on it.

But I face problem when:

1) Editing a record. For example I have table Employee, I have record with column `fullName` and its value is `Joe B`, when I want to change it to `Joe Bloggs`, it will go to approval process and now its state is PENDING, but the old record is still exist, does Liferay has temporary table to store the new value (`Joe Bloggs`)? And how do we usually handle it inside Kaleo in Liferay?

2) Deleting a record. How Kaleo handle it? because I see Kaleo only play in column `status`, CMIIW.

On 2 cases above I have my own way to handle it manually outside Kaleo ways, but I hope there is such elegant ways in Kaleo which I dont know how right now

Comment: Kaleo provides a framework which can also be integrated with a custom entity when any CRUD operation is performed on an entity.Once integrated,the workflow states are managed by Kaleo which updates the entity status based on user action.

Answer (score 0):

1. The value of all the fields related to the asset (even a pending asset) is stored in the `workflowcontext` field (as a hash map) of the `kaleotaskinstancetoken` table. I confirmed this in Liferay 7.0, pretty sure the same applies to 6.2.

Edit to add: You would of course access this via the API.

Edited again to add (piggy-backing off of the useful comment from @Shivam): See [here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/workflow-enabling-entities) to learn about workflow enabling custom entities for Liferay's workflow framework. Once you do that you really don't need to worry about the inner workings of the framework.

I don't think I understand question 2.